# Scripting Other Scripts that Call less and Require User Input to Continue

Tags: bash

I'm building a bash script that runs a number of different scripts in sequence. One of the scripts (https://get.rvm.io) calls `less` and requires a user to press `q` to continue. What is the best way to automate this to is can run sequentially with the other scripts (and ideally not require pressing 'q')? I'm currently calling the script using:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --gems=rails
```

Comment: look qt the options you can set in the `LESS` environment variable. I think there is something like 'auto-quit'. Good luck.

Comment: Why do you want to call `less` if you don't need to wait for the user to acknowledge they have seen the content of the file displayed? What are you trying to achieve overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | LESS=-X+Gq bash -s stable --ruby --gems=rails
```

The `-X` option prevents the terminal from switching to the alternate buffer. The `+` executes the rest of the characters as commands when `less` starts. `G` goes to the end of the file and `q` quits.